# Define a hidden text field to pass an array and set the array value one by one by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I want to pass an array by a html text field like

```
<input type="text" name="array[]" id="array-field">
```

and want to set this array value one by one by javascript before submit the form.

I have tried this by following code but it is sending only last value or replacing the previous value by next value.

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    $('#array-field').value(entry);
});
```

How can I do that. Please help..

Comment: Alamgir. Put yourself in the place of others and ask yourself if anyone (who cannot look inside your head) would understand your question.

Comment: Hey Kobbe, thanks for replying. I just want to pass an array through an input field like <input type="text" name="field_name[]">

Comment: And want to add value of this array(field_name[]) dynamically one by one by javascript.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: I am sorry . I am new in stackoverflow. But I think you understood my question.

Comment: Hey, why the downvote? Is this my fault to join as a new comer in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Alamgir Hossain, why on earth would you do that? This is one of the wackiest questions I have seen. I can see no reason why what you want to do would make sense.

I don't know how you want to trigger filling the value of that text input. I do it with an event listener. This loops through the array, makes a string, and puts it in the value of the text input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myUselessFunction () {
            var x = ["banana","apple","lemon","mango"];
            var str = "";
            for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
                str += x[i] + " "; // space at end is to separate words
                }
            $("#array-field").val(str);
            }
        window.addEventListener("load", myUselessFunction);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="myArray" id="array-field" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```